# Creating Maven multi-module project with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven

I want to create a maven Multi-module project.
I want to create the Parent project using

```
mvn archetype:create -DgroupId=com.websystique.multimodule -DartifactId=parent-project
```

But I got this error:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.203 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-05-02T19:57:19+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/309M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Could not find goal 'create' in plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.1 among available goals crawl, create-from-project, generate, help, integration-test, jar, update-local-catalog -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoNotFoundException
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you read the error message?

```
[ERROR] Could not find goal 'create' in plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.1 among available goals crawl, create-from-project, generate, help, integration-test, jar, update-local-catalog -> [Help 1]
```

The error message tells you that the goal you've specified for the plugin (`create`) isn't one of the available options. It also lists the valid options for you:

- `crawl`
- `create-from-project`
- `generate`
- `help`
- `integration-test`
- `jar`
- `update-local-catalog`

The goal you're looking for is `generate`. For example:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.websystique.multimodule -DartifactId=parent-project
```

For more info: [`maven-archetype-plugin`](http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/plugin-info.html).